# How to format dates differently?

Tags: python

I'm working with Python and I have a list of dates in year-month-day format, and I want to convert it to just year-month.
So the beginning of my list looks like this:
['2020-02-26', '2020-02-27', '2020-02-28', '2020-02-29', '2020-03-02', '2020-03-03'....

and I want it to become this:
['2020-02', '2020-02', '2020-02', '2020-02', '2020-03', '2020-03'...

I am not sure where to start, and I'm thinking regex might be the solution, but I'm awful with it and I don't understand it.

I have months going all the way up to December, if that changes anything. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your dates are all in that fixed format, it's probably simplest just to slice off the day part:

```
dates = ['2020-02-26', '2020-02-27', '2020-02-28', '2020-02-29', '2020-03-02', '2020-03-03']
out = [d[:-3] for d in dates]
```

Output:

```
['2020-02', '2020-02', '2020-02', '2020-02', '2020-03', '2020-03']
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How did I not think of that? Super simple and it makes sense.

Comment: @ItsBigBrainTime sometimes you just need that second pair of eyes.

Answer (score 1):

If you know your dates will always be formatted as `yyyy-mm-dd` you could simply map a string split to each item in the list:

```py
year_month_day = ['2020-02-26', '2020-02-27', '2020-02-28', '2020-02-29', '2020-03-02', '2020-03-03']
year_month = list(map(lambda date: "-".join(date.split("-")[:-1]), year_month_day))
```

This works by removing everything after the last `-` for each item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Since the dates you are using are in a `string` format, you can always remove the last 3 characters on each date `string`. Obviously with a `for` cycle to go through the array. Someting like this:

```
dates = ['2020-12-31', '2021-01-31'];

for date in range(len(dates)):
    dates[date] = dates[date][:-3]

print(dates)
```

The previous code will output: `['2020-12', '2021-01']`

Answer (score 0):

You already know the required date length, so slicing can be used.

```
dates = ['2020-02-26', '2020-02-27', '2020-02-28', '2020-02-29', '2020-03-02', '2020-03-03']
newdates = [date[0:7] for date in dates]
print(newdates)
```

Output:

```
['2020-02', '2020-02', '2020-02', '2020-02', '2020-03', '2020-03']
```